# How to convert the name of a dataframe to a string in R?

Tags: r

I am looping over a list of dataframes in R and want to use their names as part of the filename I save my plots under.

The code below is my attempt at iterating through dataframes, plotting their first column (var1) versus their second (var2) and then saving the plot.

```
first.data = data.frame( var1 = 1:4, var2 = 5:8 );
second.data = data.frame( var1 = 9:12, var2 = 13:16 );

for ( dataFrame in list(first.data, second.data) ) {
     plot( dataFrame[["var1"]], dataFrame[["var2"]] );
     dev.copy( pdf, paste( dataFrame, "_var1_vs_var2.pdf", sep="" ) );
     dev.off();
}
```

I expect this loop to produce PDF files with filenames of the form "first.data_var1_vs_var2.pdf" but instead the name of the data frame is replaced with the first column in the frame and so I get something like "c(1, 2, 3, 4)_var1_vs_var2.exchemVbuffer.pdf".

Comment: It's more difficulty and less likely that you'll get a response as your code isn't reproducible (i.e. I can't run it because you haven't supplied a data set).  Check out this [LINK](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to learn how to do this.

Comment: Loop through the names of the list instead of the list elements.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The only way I know to work this way directly on the dataframes in a list would be to attach a comment that holds the name, which you can then use to carry its name inside the loop:

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(10), var2=rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(10), var2=rnorm(10))
comment(df1) <- "df1"
comment(df2) <- "df2"

for ( dataFrame in list(df1,df2) ) { 
     dFnm <- comment(dataFrame) 
     pdf(file=paste( dFnm, "_var1_vs_var2.pdf", sep="" ))
     plot( dataFrame[["var1"]], dataFrame[["var2"]] )     
     dev.off();
}
```

(You do lose the names of objects when they get passed as the loop variables. If you do `deparse(substitute())` inside that loop, you get "dataFrame" rather than the original names.) The other way would be to use names of the dataframes, but then you will need to use `get` or `do.call`, which might get a bit messier. This way seems fairly straightforward.

Comment: That's genius, never thought about that.  +1

Comment: A little less automated than I had hoped.  If I had numerous data frames this method could become unwieldy.  However it does the job for my particular case of five data frames.  Muchos gracias!

Answer (score 20):

The code below answers the question in the title, but may or may not be of any help regarding the question in the body of the post:

```
my.data <- read.table(text='
    x1    x2     x3
     1    10    111
     2    20    222
     3    30    333
     4    40    444
     5    50    555
', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

my.data

deparse(substitute(my.data))

# [1] "my.data"
```

I found this solution here:

https://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg60789.html

after fairly extensive searching and thought if might be helpful to others to include the code with the current question, which is the first hit I get when searching the internet for: `convert data frame name to string r`.

The answer by BondedDust does mention `deparse`.

Here is code that appears to address the question in the body of the post.  Although I left out the code for plot generation:

```
df1 <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(10), var2=rnorm(10))
df2 <- data.frame(var1=rnorm(10), var2=rnorm(10))

list.function <-  function() { 

     sapply(c("df1", "df2"), get, environment(), simplify = FALSE) 
} 

my.list <- list.function()

my.df.names <- names(my.list)
# [1] "df1" "df2"

for (i in 1:length(my.list) ) {

     df.name <- my.df.names[i]
     print(df.name)

}

[1] "df1"
[1] "df2"
```

Comment: So to others: just keep in mind that the simple answer is `deparse(substitute(your_df))`.

Comment: Thanks @MarkMiller and @MSBerends I struggled with this when using it inside a function where I passed in the df name e.g. clean_data(df1). I wanted to report "dataframe df1 is cleaned". When I used `deparse(substitute(df1))` in the paste it gave me a dput like structure of all the data and not the name of the dataframe. How do you get this to work with parameters passed into a function?

Comment: Perhaps it’s some of the `sys.calls()`?

Comment: Thanks this helped me a lot! AND I don't think there's in easy equivalent in Python that can do this in Pandas (i.e., take the name of a dataframe and make it a string)! The Lord Always Delivers!

Answer (score 8):

Slightly different solution:

```
dataframe1 = data.frame(iv = rnorm(50), dv = rnorm(50))
dataframe2 = data.frame(iv = rnorm(50), dv = rnorm(50))
dataframe3 = data.frame(iv = rnorm(50), dv = rnorm(50))

LIST = list(dataframe1 = dataframe1,
            dataframe2 = dataframe2,
            dataframe3 = dataframe3)


for(i in 1:length(LIST)){
  pdf(file=paste(names(LIST)[i], paste(colnames(LIST[[i]]), collapse="."), 
                 "pdf", sep="."))
  plot(LIST[[i]][,1],LIST[[i]][,2], 
       xlab = colnames(LIST[[i]])[1], 
       ylab = colnames(LIST[[i]])[2],
       main = paste("Plot based on data in", names(LIST)[i]))
  dev.off()
  }
```

Comment: A bit too verbose for my tastes, but an interesting variation.  Thanks for the contribution.