# Creating new, variable-name dependent columns in a function (to indicate levels of significance in expression data)

Tags: r, function, if-statement

In dfs containing results of differentially expressed proteins, I would like to mark which proteins exceed certain thresholds of significance (eg logFC>1 & p<0.05 as up_0.05 or p<0.01 as up_0.01).
Using ifelse I can do this for each df individually, but it would be much cleaner to have a function as I have many dfs to process this way.

A similar question has been asked ([dplyr - mutate: use dynamic variable names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26003574/dplyr-mutate-use-dynamic-variable-names)) but I was not able to translate this into solving my problem, so I would appreciate it very much if you could correct my functions code to work (example data provided)

Thanks a lot!

## sample data

```
p.vals <- seq(from=0, to=1, by=.0001)
logFCs <- seq(from=0, to=4, by=.1)


diffEx_proteins <- data.frame(protein=LETTERS[1:1000],
                          adj.P.Val=sample(p.vals, size=1000, replace=TRUE),
                          logFC=sample(logFCs, size=1000, replace=TRUE))
```

## function

```
mark_significants <- function(comparison){
comparison$paste0(comparison, "up_0.05") <- ifelse(comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & comparison$logFC >= 1, TRUE, FALSE)
comparison$paste0(comparison, "down_0.05") <- ifelse(comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & comparison$logFC <= -1, TRUE, FALSE)
comparison$paste0(comparison, "up_0.01") <- ifelse(comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.01 & comparison$logFC >= 1, TRUE, FALSE)
comparison$paste0(comparison, "down_0.01") <- ifelse(comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.01 & comparison$logFC <= -1, TRUE, FALSE)
}
```

## usage

```
mark_significants(diffEx_proteins)
```

I get the error "Error in mark_significants(diffEx_proteins) : 
  invalid function in complex assignment"

I would like to get the df with 4 added logical columns, indicating wether proteins reach the defined threshold levels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Several problems with the syntax that I will explain below. Here is the fixed function:

```
mark_significants <- function(comparison){
    comparison[,"up_0.05"] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & comparison$logFC >= 1
    comparison[,"down_0.05"] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & comparison$logFC <= -1
    comparison[,"up_0.01"] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.01 & comparison$logFC >= 1
    comparison[,"down_0.01"] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.01 & comparison$logFC <= -1
    return(comparison)
}

test <- mark_significants(diffEx_proteins)
head(test, 3)
#  protein adj.P.Val logFC up_0.05 down_0.05 up_0.01 down_0.01
#1       A    0.9612   1.4   FALSE     FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
#2       B    0.8271   3.1   FALSE     FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
#3       C    0.1829   2.5   FALSE     FALSE   FALSE     FALSE
```

1. `comparison` is a `data.frame` and thus the function `paste0` does not know what to paste. In essence, it collates character strings. I assume that you wanted to add a column, an in my edit, I use the squared brackets with a new name to. Unlike calling `comparison$up_0.05`, which would also work here, adding a new column from within the squared brackets enables dynamic naming of the column - such as through the `paste0` function.
2. The `ifelse` function is not necessary if the result is `TRUE/FALSE` and the comparison can be directly vectorized form the whole column.
3. Lastly, the variables modified within a function are not changed outside of it, unless specified. Therefore, we have to tell `R` to output the result of the function through the `return`. To directly modify the original data, you can use `diffEx_proteins <- mark_significants(diffEx_proteins)`.

### Edit

Following additional information in the comment, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10657007) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24310574) posts offer a solution. In short, the name of the `data.frame` has to be extracted before the data enter the function, otherwise `deparse(substitute())` returns the whole `data.frame`. Here, the function will accept the name of the `data.frame` as a **character vector**, `get` the data from the name and `paste` the name to column names of the result.

```
mark_significants <- function(comparison){
    dat <- get(comparison)
    dat[,paste(comparison,"up_0.05", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & dat$logFC >= 1
    dat[,paste(comparison,"down_0.05", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & dat$logFC <= -1
    dat[,paste(comparison,"up_0.01", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.01 & dat$logFC >= 1
    dat[,paste(comparison,"down_0.01", sep = "_")] <- dat$adj.P.Val <= 0.01 & dat$logFC <= -1
    return(dat)
}

test1 <- mark_significants(deparse(substitute(diffEx_proteins)))
test2 <- mark_significants("diffEx_proteins")
identical(test1, test2)
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: This is a cleaner solution than the one I found below. I ended up defining comparison and its name separately (once as df, then as a character) and putting it together afterwards but yours trumps that. Thanks a lot for the effort!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much nya, that brought me on the right track to the solution!
Only I wanted to add the name of the "comparison" to the new columns as I am using the colnames later on for a VENN diagram.

Here is my modified version of your function that includes the "comparison" into the colnames (your hint about comparison being a dataframe helped to solve its correct usage)

```
mark_significants_2 <- function(comparison){
 comparison[,paste0("comparison","_up_0.05")] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & comparison$logFC >= 1
 comparison[,paste0("comparison","_down_0.05")] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & comparison$logFC <= -1
 comparison[,paste0("comparison","_up_0.01")] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.01 & comparison$logFC >= 1
 comparison[,paste0("comparison","_down_0.01")] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.01 & comparison$logFC <= -1
 return(comparison)
}
```

Slowly im getting into writing functions, your hints were great to understand the syntax issues!

Comment: Yes, using a character string in `paste0` will create the new names. It was not apparent from your original question.

Comment: Unfortunatly its not finished yet. I would like to add the name of the "comparison. I tried: 
comparison[,paste0("up_0.05_", deparse(substitute(comparison)))] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & comparison$logFC >= 1

but it wont work (it crashes R). Any suggestions how I could append the original name of my comparison to the new colname?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Working but inelegant solution, separating dataframe and its name:

```
mark_significants_3 <- function(comparison, name){
 comparison[,paste0(name, "_up_0.05")] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & 
comparison$logFC >= 1
 comparison[,paste0(name, "_down_0.05")] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.05 & c 
comparison$logFC <= -1
 comparison[,paste0(name, "_up_0.001")] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.001 & 
comparison$logFC >= 1
 comparison[,paste0(name, "_down_0.001")] <- comparison$adj.P.Val <= 0.001 & 
comparison$logFC <= -1
 return(comparison)
 } 

test3 <- mark_significants_3(diffEx_proteins, "diffEx_proteins")
```